# Shrink UIStackView Child

Tags: swift, uistackview

I just want to ask if its possible to have a two column UIViews inside a UIStackView. What I mean is I don't want to put another 2 UIStackView inside the parent stack view to achieved this.

**WHAT I GOT:**

[image]

**WHAT I WANT:**

[image]

Comment: No you have to stack the stackviews.  Stackview is the equivalent of android's linearLayout, but there is no iOS equivalent of the android  gridLayout.

Comment: Sad to hear that there is no equivalent gridview of android in ios. I want to have a 10 column in a stackview and I want to drag uiviews between columns. Now this is a pain to drag the uiview reorderably. If their parent is the same that would be easy that's why I'm asking if that's possible. Btw, thanks Marius :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to perform following steps

1. Create stackviews containing 2 images, each having horizontal Axis
2. Add each of these stackviews into single stack view with vertical Axis

Comment: Thank you for answering. So this is not possible unless I add two stackviews inside of the Horizontal Axis stackview?

Comment: Yes.. without having 2 stackviews, it is not possible using single stackView.. If you know what is meaning of "stack" word, then you will get concept of stack view easily, Stack is 1-D list , now as the content you want,  it is clearly not a 1-D list, for having 1-D list, you need to create list from inner contens, i mean you need to create multiple stacks each having horizontal directions and add it into single stack with vertical direction... you will get the what you want